# Search in php cURL with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, curl

```
function curl_download($Url){
     $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.example.org/yay.htm");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "MozillaXYZ/1.0");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
}

$curl = curl_download('http://www.example.com');

<script>
    $(function() {
        var myhtml = "<?=$curl;?>";
    });
</script>
```

This just outputs the whole website on my webpage. instead of putting in a variable in Javascript.
I think would like to mainpulate it like standard HTML code.

Thanks ahead.

Comment: Would you be able to add why you want to do it this way? PHP can parse and modify html (http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net) so it might be best to do it server side.

Comment: prbably, because there is an `"` in the curled html which marked the end of the variable

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it's the best way to achieve this. If you store the whole html result in the js variable, javascript throws errors due to multiline and unescaped double and single quotes.
You could use that function as a server-side endpoint, and call it through ajax in js. Jquery would handle the html response (avoiding quotes conflicts and new lines), and you could use the result as a parameter in the success callback.

Comment: Running an Ajax call on the cUrl variable? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Create a route, or another endpoint (I don't know exactly the structure of your program, but it could be also the same page), and then call that endpoint via ajax.
A "single page" endpoint would be something like this:
https://gist.github.com/desmondhume/18aec0622f06d57afcbb

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the HTML. Perhaps run it through `json_encode`? That may handle all of the escaping for you.